# How to Integrate HTML, Python (Pandas) and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, pandas

I am currently working on an invoice generation system. I have designed the front end with HTML. The Database is in an excel. Thus I thought of using Python (Pandas).

When I enter a number in a text field in the HTML, the value must be fetched and has to be searched in the excel.

[The front end looks like this If that Invoice number is entered, the number has to be fetched and has to find the matching in the excel and print the detail in the below grids from the excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsPEl.jpg)

[Sample of the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAggL.png)

I have no idea or knowledge in Java or SQL.

```
<h1>Recipient</h1>
            <article>
            <address contenteditable>
            <p>Mr. Client Name<br>Client Company Name</p>
            </address>
            <table class="meta">
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Invoice #</span></th>
                    <td><span contenteditable>12345</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Date</span></th>
                    <td><span contenteditable>January 1, 2012</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Amount Due</span></th>
                    <td><span id="prefix" contenteditable>&#x20B9;</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="inventory">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Item</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>LR Number</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Description</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Rate</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Quantity</span></th>
                        <th><span contenteditable>Price</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable>Front End Consultation</span></td>
                        <td><span contenteditable>655</span></td>
                        <td><span contenteditable>Experience Review</span></td>
                        <td><span data-prefix>&#x20B9;</span><span contenteditable>150.00</span></td>
                        <td><span contenteditable>4</span></td>
                        <td><span data-prefix>&#x20B9;</span><span>600.00</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Excel is not really suitable for database data. Learn to use PHP and mySQL instead. You'll only need 1% of each for this anyway.

Comment: there is nothing wrong to use python+panda (although excel may not be a good choice), no need to learn PHP and mySQL.

Comment: My doubt is how to post in the HTML.